# How display error message without error page when database error occured in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables **Product** and **Purchase**. 
I set a `on delete restrict` FK in `product.purchase_id` column with `purchase.purchase_id` column. Then  if I try to delete product.product_id with FK, It shows error just like

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1451

Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`another_bata`.`product_purchase_item`, CONSTRAINT `FK_product_purchase_item_1` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `product` (`product_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)

delete from product where product_id='158'

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\rima_shoe\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

But I want only alert for this. so I just try a `try...catch` syntax my code is here

```
  try{
      $this->db->query("delete from product where product_id='$delete'");
  }
   catch (Exception $e) {
              echo "an error occured during query" ;
   }
```

But this code doesn't work. it also display above error in a white page...

Comment: What's your question?  You can't use `try`/`catch` for this because `$this->db->query` doesn't throw an `Exception` when it fails.  You should fix your SQL query.

Comment: so how can I solve my problem... A user don't like this database error page if user try a FK id. I just want ignore this page, I want a session flash data or $data['test'] to trans this error message

Comment: It's better to *fix* an SQL error versus just ignoring it.  Try to run a `SELECT` first to check if the row exists.  If it doesn't, then don't run the `DELETE` and return your own error.

Comment: how can I fix sql error? I set a `on delete restrict` FK in product.purchase_id. so if user try to delete this include key, database must show an error.........

Comment: Try to run a `SELECT` query first to make sure the row/key you want exists.

Comment: is it possible to check key on a specific id

Comment: I don't know how foreign keys work in MySQL, but I'd assume so.

Answer (score 4):

Reference [Codeigniter foreign key constraint check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463429/codeigniter-foreign-key-constraint-check)

in the database.php file find the line

```
$db['default']['db_debug']
```

and set it to FALSE. This will prevent Codeigniter from printing the error on the screen.

Also in the delete function you can check:

```
if ($this->db->_error_number() == 1451)
```

If you need to do something special when this happens.

> **Edit** Remeber that in Codeigniter 3.0 (CI3), this is now $errors = $this->db->error();

Answer (score 3):

The codeigniter query does not throw and exception. Instead use this to figure out if an error occured.

```
if ($this->db->_error_message()){
    $msg = $this->db->_error_message();

    echo $msg;
}
```

Simple as that

Comment: It doesn't throw an exception, but it still triggers a warning (which displays an error page).

Comment: @SajunaFernando sir i use  your code but it not echo errror message